# Using intersect in R with Rcpp

Tags: rcpp

I am new to Rcpp and am trying to write a simple function that would take a list of character vectors (`myList`), and a separate character vector (`vec1`), and would return a list of intersections between each list vector and vec1.

I can do this in R easily enough:

```
myList <- list(
                c('apple','banana','orange','pineapple'),
                c('pear','pineapple','watermelon'),
                c('orange','apple','pineapple'),
                NA,
                c('watermelon','lime','apple','banana'))

vec1 <- c('apple','pineapple','banana')

# R implementation
lapply(myList, function(x) intersect(x, vec1))
```

But I am confused as to how to implement this with Rcpp. Here is my attempt:

```
cppFunction('
    List intersectList (List input, StringVector vec) {

        int n = input.size();
        List out(n);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            StringVector sp = Rcpp::as< std::vector<std::string> > (input[i]);

            if (sp.length() > 0) {  
                out[i] = intersect(sp, vec);
            }
        }

        return out;

    }
')
```

...however this results in an error:

```
Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, cacheDir = cacheDir,  : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
file1510d6dbd767c.cpp:14:17: error: no viable conversion from 'std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >' to 'StringVector' (aka 'Vector<16>')
                        StringVector sp = Rcpp::as< std::vector<std::string> > (input[i]);
                                     ^    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h:65:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >' to 'const Rcpp::Vector<16, PreserveStorage> &' for 1st argument
    Vector( const Vector& other){
    ^
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h:73:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >' to 'SEXP' (aka 'SEXPREC *') for 1st argument
    Vector( SEXP x ) {
    ^
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h:101:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >' to 'const std::string &' (aka 'const basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > &') for 1st argument
    Vector( const std::string& st ){
    ^
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h:107:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >' to 'const char *' for 1st argument
    Vector( const char* st ) {
    ^
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h:128:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >' to 'const int &' for 1st argument
    Vector( const int& size ) {
    ^
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h:133:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >' to 'const Rcpp::Dimension &' for 1st argument
    Vector( const Dimension& dims) {
    ^
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h:78:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'GenericProxy' against 'vector'
    Vector( const GenericProxy<Proxy>& proxy ){
    ^
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h:123:42: note: candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if' [with T = std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >]
        typename Rcpp::traits::enable_if<traits::is_arithmetic<T>::value, void>::type* = 0) {
                                         ^
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h:146:45: note: candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if' [with T = std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >]
           typename Rcpp::traits::enable_if<traits::is_bool<T>::value && RTYPE == LGLSXP, void>::type* = 0) {
                                            ^
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h:162:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'VectorBase' against 'vector'
    Vector( const VectorBase<RTYPE,NA,VEC>& other ) {
    ^
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h:176:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'SingleLogicalResult' against 'vector'
    Vector( const sugar::SingleLogicalResult<NA,T>& obj ) {
    ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [file1510d6dbd767c.o] Error 1
```

In this particular case, the R implementation is simple and fast, so Rcpp may not be necessary. But I would like to understand the Rcpp implementation, as it would give me a better understanding of how to work with vectors and lists with Rcpp.

Answer (score 2):

Briefly:

1. The function is called `intersect`; your title talks about `intercept`. Not the same thing.
2. The unit test for `intersect()` is a one-liner (see below).  If I were you I'd start from it and try it with `StringVector` types.
3. You are jumping bacl and forth between `StringVector` and `std::vector<std::string>`. Why? If you change `StringVector sp = Rcpp::as< std::vector<std::string> > (input[i]);` to use `StringVector` in the `as<>()` you might be good.  [ Untested, no time right now. ]

The test function (included in every version of Rcpp in file `unitTests/cpp/sugar.cpp` is:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector runit_intersect( IntegerVector x, IntegerVector y){
    return intersect( x, y ) ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! (1) was a typo on my part, I should have read through more carefully.
I'm coming from a pure R background, and am new to Rcpp (and C++ for that matter). So far, I've been unclear on the difference between StringVector, CharacterVector and std::vector<std::string>. 
But this helps point me in the right direction! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dirk Eddelbuettel for suggesting the following:

```
> cppFunction('
+   List intersectList (List input, StringVector vec) {
+   
+       int n = input.size();
+       List out(n);
+   
+       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
+           
+           StringVector sp = Rcpp::as< StringVector > (input[i]);
+   
+           if (sp.length() > 0) {  
+               out[i] = intersect(sp, vec);
+           }
+       }
+   
+       return out;
+ 
+   }
+ ')
> 
> myList <- list(
+               c('apple','banana','orange','pineapple'),
+               c('pear','pineapple','watermelon'),
+               c('orange','apple','pineapple'),
+               NA,
+               c('watermelon','lime','apple','banana'))
>               
> vec1 <- c('apple','pineapple','banana')
> 
> intersectList(myList, vec1)
[[1]]
[1] "pineapple" "banana"    "apple"    

[[2]]
[1] "pineapple"

[[3]]
[1] "pineapple" "apple"    

[[4]]
character(0)

[[5]]
[1] "banana" "apple"
```